# createState function creates a mutable state in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

`createState`:

> Creates the mutable state for this widget at a given location in the tree.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget/createState.html

Now, in code:

```
class A extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _AState createState() => _AState();
}

class _AState extends State<A> {
}
```

Here we create a separate class named `_AState` which inherits from a predefined class named `State`?

So, what is `createState`' role here? How does it create a mutable state for us?

Comment: `createState` defines which class to use as state for this widget, in this case it says to create a `_AState`. I'm not sure exactly what you are asking here

Comment: Well, you have answered what I have asked. Please put that as an answer. @Ivo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `createState` you tell the `StatefulWidget` which class to use as state for this widget. And you tell it here that it needs to create an instance of `_AState` for this widget.

By the way, it is also recommended to write it as

```
State<A> createState() => _AState();
```

It still works the way you wrote it but the IDE might complain about

```
Avoid using private types in public APIs
```

Saying the return type is `State<A>` instead of `_AState` removes this warning.

Answer (score 0):

In order to create a stateful widget in a flutter, it uses the `createState()` method. `Stateful Widget` means a widget that has a mutable state.